# HTML tags and attributes sored in xml file

Tags: html, xml, file, tags

Does anyone own or knows where can i find a xml file containing all the HTML tags and attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3C has a version of [XHTML 1.0 expressed in a schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/).

Comment: The DTDs are probably better (since more people care about them), but since the question was looking for XML, I didn't think about them.